# Why is this python property not recognised

Tags: python

I dont usually use python properties but recently had reason to do so.
I have the following code:

```
class my_object:
    @property
    def changed(self):
        return self._changed

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name_string: str = ""):
        self._changed = True
        self._name = name_string

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description

    @description.setter
    def description(self, description_string: str = ""):
        self._changed = True
        self._description = description_string

    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._changed = False
        self._name = ""
        self._description = ""


test_object = my_object()
print("CHANGED ", test_object.changed)
print("NAME ", test_object.name)
print("DESCRIPTION ", test_object.description)

test_object.name = "John Doe"
test_object.description = "This is John's object"

print("CHANGED ", test_object.changed)
print("NAME ", test_object.name)
print("DESCRIPTION ", test_object.description)
```

When i run the script i get the message:

```
AttributeError: 'my_object' object has no attribute '_changed'. Did you mean: 'changed'?
```

But i really cant see what i have down wrong; it must be basic but i cant seee it.
Perhaps someone could tell me
thanks

Comment: typo : `__init__` not `__int__`

Answer (score 2):

You Have Typo In Constructor's Name

```
def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._changed = False
    self._name = ""
    self._description = ""
```

Change `__int__` To `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._changed = False
    self._name = ""
    self._description = ""
```